# Why char array only printing values it contain other arrays are printing their datatypes in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

```cs
char[] c = new char[] {'a','b','c'};
int[] i = new int[] {1, 2, 3};

System.Console.WriteLine(c);
System.Console.WriteLine(i);
```

In this code the char array (`c`)'s print statement prints it values like 'a','b','c' but in the int array it prints the datatype of array. What is the reason for this?

Comment: WriteLine writes strings. To get a string if it wasn't in the first place the ToString() method is called. And then its up to the implementation of ToString() what you get to see. Default implementation is to return the type name and for complex types it isn't obvious how a string should look so that is ok. But for basic datatypes there are often implemented as a "real" type conversion.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-7.0#system-console-writeline(system-char())

Answer (score 1):

When `Console.WriteLine()` is called with an object different than a `char[]`, it invokes `ToString()` and that object.

> A string is an object of type String whose value is text. Internally, the text is stored as a sequential read-only collection of Char objects.

```cs
char [] c = new char[] {'a','b','c'};
int [] i =new int[] {1,2,3};
```

When you call `Console.WriteLine(c)` you are already providing an `char[]` that will be copied to the Console stream.

But when you call `Console.WriteLine(i)`, you are actually calling `Console.WriteLine(i.ToString())`, and `i.ToString()` is `Array.ToString()` which returns the dataType.